# Good Open Source Package Manager for OSX

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, package-management, open-source

I am new to OSX, having been a Linux user for years I am used to work with apt and how nice is just to update and upgrade mi computer software.

What is the best similar solution for OSX for open source packages like VIM, Python, Ruby ... and easily mantain them updated? I have read about Macports and Hombrew, ... would even PIP be appropiate for the task?

What is exactly GEM?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Hi AlexN. Unfortunately, product recommendation questions are off topic on Super User. Additionally, asking for "best" solutions without specifying a metric by which to judge solutions is prone to draw opinionated answers, which is something we strive very hard to avoid. I recommend you [edit] your question to make it more about how to solve a specific problem, and less about seeking product recommendations. Also, please ask only a single question per question. That would make the question more likely to meet our standards. See the [help] section on asking questions for further guidance.

Comment: I have not asked for the best solution, I was just asking for some information about the present situation of packages managers in OSX, a lot like the answer Schwertspize has provided. Thanks.

Comment: Your question explicitly contains the phrase "What is **the best** similar solution for OSX (...)?". (My emphasis.)

Comment: My apologies then, you are right. I will be more careful with how I structure sentences in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also think, this don't belong here, but I answer, like you asked about the tools in general.

MacPorts is the Mac version of the bsd package manager "port" (Mac is in fact a bsd derivate, not Linux). homebrew is a (as I know) package manager written from scratch. MacPorts does his magic in the /opt directory, homebrew normally ins /usr/local/Cellar. the fact, I prefer homebrew, is that you can install homebrew just via cloning a git repo, adapting path and that's it. you can install homebrew everywhere, updates come via `git pull` and all packages are prefixed into that directory. additionally permissions are managed so you don't need sudo.

pip is a python package manager, it serves python packages, ruby gems are the same written in ruby

one last word: any package manager won't update your system. it installs the packages from scratch and modify the path so you actually use those tools installed. they are not ment to keep your system up-to-date, they should provide **additional** software